# ECMAScript 5.1 specification incorrect? Date constructor date/time format parsed as UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, ecmascript-5, iso8601

According to wikipedia's [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601/) article (I know, bad source)...

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation, the time is assumed to be in local time.

So, for example.. given:

- var a = Date.parse("2012-03-21");
- var b = Date.parse("2012-03-21T00:00");
- var c = Date.parse("2012-03-21T00:00Z");

I would expect "a" and "b" to be local time (the browser's time zone) while "c" is UTC.  However, a, b, and c are all equivalent (1332288000000).  All values are parsed as UTC.

The ECMAScript specification also clearly states this:

> 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format
>
> The value of an absent time zone offset is "Z".

Why is there this discrepancy?  Is wikipedia incorrect or the ECMAScript spec?  How would one parse an ISO-8601 string into local time in the browser (without knowing the browser's time zone) ?

Comment: well, perhaps the browsers timezone actually is UTC?

Comment: Strange comment.  No, it's EST.

Comment: what's so strange about this comment, if you are in UK, your localtime and utc yield the same result...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ES5.1 is incorrect.

The ECMAScript 6 draft now says "If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time."

Answer (score 1):

> How would one parse an ISO-8601 string into local time in the browser (without knowing the browser's time zone) ?

Use the `toLocaleString` method to do this:

```
var foo = new Date("2012-03-21").toLocaleString()
var bar = new Date("2012-03-21T00:00").toLocaleString()
var baz = new Date("2012-03-21T00:00Z").toLocaleString()
```

**References**

- [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)